# PHP Constant include

Tags: php

I have a problem in PHP and I am trying for 2 hours to solve this problem.

I have an application and I would like that all users start at the index.php file. This file includes the login file and also a content file.

Now, normally a user can access directly the content.php file.

For that reason I have defined a constant which is set when a user starts at index.php.

This file looks like

```
define('NAME','X');
include("Login.php");
include("content.php");
```

Now I define the constant and I would like to check in my included files if this constant is set to show my data. In the Login file this works with no problems. 
Then I have the second and if I just write it like this it works:

```
    if(defined('NAME'))
    {
        showContent();
    }
```

But I have also $_POST Check and with that it doesn't work!

```
if(defined('NAME'))
{
if (isset ( $_POST ["Login"] ) ) 
{
    if ($_POST ["Login"] == "True" ) {      
        echo showContent();
    }
}
}
```

With no if(defined('NAME')) surrounding it works fine! I get the post variables from a javascript file.

Can you explain me why it works just with the defined if and not with the second?

Obviously the constant is defined correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: you know, that a constant won't persist throughout the pages? Better use something like `$_SESSION['hasseenindex']`.

Comment: If your condintion if(defined('NAME')) return false then probably your post request is not calling index.php script. Can you show us your html form?

Comment: Javascript file sends values to what php file?

Answer (score 0):

The constant is not like a session value, it does not persist across multiple pages.

When you do a POST request to your page, the constant is no longer defined and therefore your code does not get executed.

It you're using the constant as a security measure to prevent unauthorized access, you could consider doing the "opposite" of what you're doing now, instead of checking if the constant is set, check if it's not and then do a 403.

```
if(!defined('NAME')) {
    die('403');
}
```